# Creating a new table in quickbooks online database

Tags: php, quickbooks-online

I work quick books onlineV3 .  One of my table is not available in quick books online database.

How do I create the above new table in quick books online database ?

If the above new table cannot be created, can you tell me, what options i got ?

Looking forward your earliest reply,

Comment: Can you please share more details. Which table are you talking about ? Are you using V3 REST endpoint ?

Answer (score 0):

The QuickBooks Online APIs are not even table-based. They have an SQL-like query language, but it's not an SQL database, and it has no concept of "tables".

Further, there's no way to "create new tables" as you indicate.

You may want to re-read the documentation, and re-word your question, as the question you're asking doesn't seem to really make much sense...

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services

Comment: Thanks, for your reply. Presently, i read the data from my customer table in my MYSQL database and insert the data into to the customer entity { Which exist already }in online quickbooks. Done by PHP-DEV KIT.  Works fine. I have another table in my MYSQL database. I want to create a new entity { It is not present in quick books online database } for this in the online quick books. Then, i want to insert the records into it like as i did above for the customer. Can you tell me how to do the above ?  Looking forward your reply ASAP, Thanks..

Comment: Look at the link I posted above - it shows every object type available within QuickBooks Online. If you don't see it there, you can't access it/create records of that type.